# model.matrix raises memory allocation error

Tags: r, memory-management, sparse-matrix

I am using `model.matrix` to create many columns out of an existing data frame. The goal is to create many columns each of which will have a name equal to a distinct value of one feature column (`my_one_feature`). That is, if `my_one_feature` is a categorical variable with values `{cat_1,cat_2,cat_3}`, I expect 3 additional columns to be generated with name: `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3` and the values for each will be 0 or 1 depending on their presence in corresponding row.

```
mm <- model.matrix(~factor(my_one_feature)-1,data=my_data_frame)
```

then I can

```
cbind(my_data_frame,mm)
```

I think the function task is exactly what I explained. However for large data and/or large feature values, it gives a memory allocation error:

```
cannot allocate vector of size 50 Gb
```

I know the resulting matrix will be sparse. How to avoid this memory allocation problem?

Here is an example with 4 original features with only 7 rows:

```
f1<-c('f1_1','f1_2','f1_1','f1_3','f1_3','f1_1','f1_4')
f2<-c(1,2,3,4,2,4,2)
f3<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
f4<-c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1)`

my_data_frame<-data.frame(f1,f2,f3,f4)
```

It looks like:

```
my_data_frame
    f1 f2 f3 f4
1 f1_1  1  1  0
2 f1_2  2  2  0
3 f1_1  3  3  1
4 f1_3  4  4  1
5 f1_3  2  5  1
6 f1_1  4  6  0
7 f1_4  2  7  1

mm<-sparse.model.matrix(~factor(f1)-1,data=my_data_frame)
```

looks like:

```
7 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  factor(f1)f1_1 factor(f1)f1_2 factor(f1)f1_3 factor(f1)f1_4
1              1              .              .              .
2              .              1              .              .
3              1              .              .              .
4              .              .              1              .
5              .              .              1              .
6              1              .              .              .
7              .              .              .              1
```

how to combine my_data_frame with *mm* such that resulting object can have all features columns `(f1, f2, f3, f4, factor(f1)f1_1, factor(f1)f1_2, factor(f1)f1_3, factor(f1)f1_4))` and of course 7 rows.

Ok

your answer give this results on my rstudio tool:

```
> my_data_frame <- data.frame(
+     f1=c('f1_1','f1_2','f1_1','f1_3','f1_3','f1_1','f1_4'),
+     f2=c(1,2,3,4,2,4,2),
+     f3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
+     f4=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1))
> library("Matrix")
> mm <- sparse.model.matrix(~factor(f1)-1,
+                           data=my_data_frame)
> new_data_frame <- cbind(Matrix(as.matrix(my_data_frame[,-1])),
+                         mm)
> dim(new_data_frame)
[1] 1 2
> str(new_data_frame)
List of 2
 $ :Formal class 'dgeMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:21] 1 2 3 4 2 4 2 1 2 3 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 7 3
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "f2" "f3" "f4"
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:7] 0 2 5 1 3 4 6
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:5] 0 3 4 6 7
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 7 4
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "factor(f1)f1_1" "factor(f1)f1_2" "factor(f1)f1_3" "factor(f1)f1_4"
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:7] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 1 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "" "mm"
> 


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257  LC_CTYPE=Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257    LC_MONETARY=Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257 LC_NUMERIC=C                         
[5] LC_TIME=Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.3      lattice_0.20-30 tools_3.1.3    
>
```

Comment: it's still going to be tough/impossible to include `f1` in the result ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks. Result is fine, i dont need f1 anyway. However, this new_data_frame is still not combining all f2,f3,f4 with other factor variables. new_data_frame[1,1] and new_data_frame[1,2] would extract two matrices. How to merge both to have object with all columns.. I want to have all columns in one object and want to export it to file later.

Comment: We must be talking past each other.  Did you see my updated answer below? It produces a 7x7 matrix,  which does indeed contain all of the information in the original matrix.

Comment: Well, maybe you forgot to update your answer. I dont see 7x7 matrix as result. new_data_frame is a object with combined data structure. See your answer, I added the exploration of this new_data_frame and its set of two different matrices.

Comment: I **strongly** suspect that you did not actually run the updated code I provided.  Your edit mangled my question.  Do you **really** get the results you pasted into my question if you run exactly the code I provided in a clean session???

Comment: your answer give me different result (ok this time I put line by line execution of your answer, at the end of my question, u will see results). Its strange how u are getting different result?

Comment: Now I get your result, but its using  _cbind2_ (not _cbind_). Wonder how you got 7x7 by using _cbind_ But cbind2 also changes . to 0 so resulting matrix is of large size. Therefore, problem is still not being solved.

Comment: can I have the results of `sessionInfo()` please ?

Comment: just added, at the end of question.

Comment: @BenBolker what do you think now? From the result of sessionInfo.

Comment: it's puzzling.  Nothing jumps out at me. I've tried this on Ubuntu/32bit/r-devel and `R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)` both with Matrix 1.2-2.  Unless we can get someone else to reproduce your problem I'm going to have to give up.

Comment: Well, I have solved the issue in another way. Could you tell me how to write this sparse matrix to a file, like we write a data table? In real data I have >2000 columns and text file should have tab separated columns like csv file. Row.names and col.names should be false (that is, not appear). I know these arguments in write.table function, but unfortunately that only writes a data frame.

Comment: please ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Set up data:

```
 my_data_frame <- data.frame(
 f1=c('f1_1','f1_2','f1_1','f1_3','f1_3','f1_1','f1_4'),
 f2=c(1,2,3,4,2,4,2),
 f3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
 f4=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1))
```

Now use `sparse.model.matrix` for the categorical feature:

```
library("Matrix")
mm <- sparse.model.matrix(~factor(f1)-1,
           data=my_data_frame)
```

Bind it back to the numerical predictors (coerce `data.frame` -> `matrix` -> `Matrix`):

```
new_data_frame <- cbind(Matrix(as.matrix(my_data_frame[,-1])),
                        mm)
```

Results:

```
dim(new_data_frame)
## [1] 7 7 
str(new_data_frame)
## Formal class 'dgeMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 4 slots
##   ..@ x       : num [1:49] 1 2 3 4 2 4 2 1 2 3 ...
##   ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 7 7
##   ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "f2" "f3" "f4" "factor(f1)f1_1" ...
##   ..@ factors : list()

object.size(new_data_frame) ## 1596 bytes
```

The result does *not* contain the original `f1` column, because matrices can't have heterogeneous types -- but there would be no way to use that column its raw form for numerical modeling and prediction in any case ...

Session info  (OP is using 3.1.3/windows 8 x64/Lithuanian locale/Matrix_1.2-2/tools_3.1.3):

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.2.1      lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: thanks. This does not give memory error. However mm will be of dgCMatrix type. When I try to cbind it with original my_data_frame it gives: _cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame_ error

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but what about `cbind(Matrix(as.matrix(my_data_frame))),mm)` ?

Comment: `df<-cbind(Matrix(as.matrix(my_data_frame)),mm)`
_Error in .M.kind(data) : 
  not yet implemented for matrix with typeof character_

Comment: I just needed to bind original data frame with extra columns being generated as in _mm_. The way you just said is binding two matrices. Ok but maybe better that mm could be changed to dataframe instead? then both dataframe can be bind easily. I did not find the way yet.

Comment: The point is that there is no such thing as a sparse data frame, only sparse matrices.  If you can give a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) I or someone else can try to iron out the wrinkles

Comment: Ok. but the error _.M.kind(data) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof character_ is due to that `typeof(as.matrix(my_data_frame))` is _"character"_. But I dont know why _cbind_ of this dataframe turned into matrix is not possible with _mm_. How to make it work

Comment: Its bit hectic to give reproducible example for this kind of data I have. Maybe the above my comment would help to know better reason?

Comment: I dont see the explaination you gave with reproducble example answer what I asked. Purpose of combing matrix to original data frame is to "combine" them. If original data frame has let say 5 feature columns, and one of columns has been used to create sparse matrix mm , then combining both should give me data frame(or matrix as u said data frame not possible) with rows number same as in original and columns= all original 5 columns plus generated columns as in mm. You explanation with only sub setting or indexing by each column does not appropriate the reasoning of the original question.

Comment: Also dont forget that your example assume A-Z 26 rows and 26 columns, actually rows can be more than 26 (e.g. M letter can be many times, in a data), but the column still 26. This would lead to error: _Error in dimnamesGets(x, value) : 
  invalid dimnames given for “dgCMatrix” object_ if you do `rownames(mm) <- my_data_frame$name`

Comment: I think I'm going to give up now.  You  haven't given an example of *what you want to do with this object*.  It's impossible to have a matrix (including a sparse matrix) with heterogeneous column types, so you'll have to find a way to do whatever it is you're trying to do (which I still don't know).

Comment: Actually if you got the point, my second last comment simply detail what i want to do. Combining two objects with same rows but different columns means resulting to a new object with columns from both objects. Cbind does that given 2 data frames. In current problem the 2 objects are: data frame and sparse matrix.

Comment: it's impossible, unless you write your own data structure.  I know *what* you want to do, narrowly speaking. I know it's impossible. I don't know *why* you want to do it. If I knew what you wanted to do with the resulting object I might be able to give you advice on how to do it.

Comment: I need resulting object for modelling tasks. The original information (original 5 features of original data frame) + binarized features as in _mm_. Its very obvious. _mm_ was generated considering only one feature from original data frame, why would I not like to combine _mm_ with original data frame given original data frame has other 4 features which i obviously want. Question is not why I want - coz its information and I need to have it for modelling task.

Comment: are all of those features also categorical variables?  are some numeric? **Can you please give a reproducible example**?

Comment: please see the example  at (edited question) Hope now its clear :)